# The cost of these aircrafts in modern US dollar?

Tags: aviation-history, cost

Could you tell me where I can find the development cost and market price of a Fairey Rotodyne, Convair CV-240, Martin 4-0-4, Ka-22 in current US dollar?

Comment: 1) find the contemporary cost 2) use an inflation calculation https://www.usinflationcalculator.com/ 3) profit!

Comment: The problems is that there are a lot of technical data of those aircraft, but not much financial data